# How to solve «this map file is too big. please choose a different map»?

Tags: warcraft-3, warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne

In Warcraft 3: The Frozen Throne, when you try to load some maps, a message appear explaining (not much): «this map file is too big. please choose a different map».

But why does this happen? How can I solve this and play the map?

I tried to play some maps like Lordaeron The Aftermath, and Lordaeron The Foremath in Singleplayer, with computer (bots), but the message keeps appearing to me.

My Warcraft version is 1.26.0.6401, and files I'm trying to play are respectively, 8.10MB, and 26.2MB, although I tried to play other maps large 29.743MB, 11.188MB and they didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Kaffeleif](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/87885/kaffeleif) said in comments, I've used the [Warcraft III 8MB Limit Remover](http://www.dota682.com/game-dll-warcraft-iii-8mb-limit-remover/). Changing the game `.dll` fixed my problem, and now all maps I asked for help are working properly.

It's necessary to do the following:

- Download the patch, respectively to the [1.24 version](http://www.game2g.com/dota-map/Game2e.com%201.24e%20-%20game.dll.zip) or [1.26 version](http://www.game2g.com/dota-map/Game2e.com%201.26a%20-%20game.dll.zip).
- Extract the `.zip` file.
- Copy and Paste the `game.dll` file to the Warcraft III folder.

Answer (score 3):

Patch 1.27b (Dec. 2016) raised the vanilla map size limit from 8MB to 128MB. Update your game.

Backwards compatibility hasn't been broken significantly since patch 1.24b, but forward compatibility is not guaranteed, so it's not impossible that custom maps made with newer game versions in mind won't work properly on older versions.